# Parsing Uneven data/ json object using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/prantikv/1nvdzv24/9/

i have some uneven data like so

```
[{
   "fname": "Tonja", //common
    "lname": "Mize",
    "tel": "(963)784-1098",
    "address": "3999 Quis Ln",
    "city": "Sebring",
    "state": "MI",
    "zip": 76593
},
{
    "fname": "Stella", //common
    "Othername": "Lester",
    "mobile": "(936)898-2886"
}];
```

notice only the **fname** property is common between the two objects

so when i do this

```
  <li ng-repeat="(key,val) in populationList | filter:name"> 
 {{ val.**fname**}} 
</li>
```

i do get the fname but the data is uneven so i cannot figure out how to go through over each object. also the length of the object is different as well.

what i want to do is to filter the data over a select list

```
<select ng-model="name">
    <option value="Tonja" selected="Tonja">Tonja</option>
    <option value="Stella">Stella</option>
</select>
```

but i am unable to figure out a way to display the unmatched properties of objects
is there a way i get all the key:value pairs on the sub data dynamically?

Comment: You want to form select element having options which are common between the two objects ?

Comment: i want when the user select a value form select list then all the data of that object should be displayed...for example if "Tonja" is selected then its data and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yozuwemetu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Your Html,

```
<div ng-app='app'>
 <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <select ng-options="item.fname for item in populationList | fieldList:'fname'" ng-model="myItem" ng-change="changeSelection(myItem)">
    </select>

   <li ng-repeat="key in availableKeys"> 
         {{selectedObject[key]}} 
    </li>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('filters',[]).
  filter('fieldList', function() {
      return function(populationList, parameter) {
        var filteredArray = [];
        angular.forEach(populationList, function(value, index) {
             if(value.hasOwnProperty(parameter)) {
                 filteredArray.push(value);
             }
        });
        return filteredArray;
      };
    });


angular.module('app',['filters'])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.changeSelection = function(item) {
    $scope.selectedObject = item;
    $scope.availableKeys = Object.keys($scope.selectedObject);
    };
  $scope.populationList = [{
    "fname": "Tonja", //common
    "lname": "Mize",
    "tel": "(963)784-1098",
    "address": "3999 Quis Ln",
    "city": "Sebring",
    "state": "MI",
    "zip": 76593
     },
     {
    "fname": "Stella", //common
    "Othername": "Lester",
    "mobile": "(936)898-2886"
   }];
});
```